# How to use environment variables for Springboot application using a .env file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to build a Springboot application which connects to a DB. I would like to use a `.env` file which has the sensitive content. At the first hand, I am testing by changing the port to 8081.
My .env file has the following content

```
PORT=8081
```

My application.properties has the following content

```
server.port=${PORT}
```

I have a run time error that PORT cannot be resolved, which is to be expected when I did not know how to feed the .env file to properties.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

PS: I am using the port as an example, if this succeeds I will also set the DB Credentials with the .env file.

**UPDATE:**
I would prefer using `.env` file because when the application is deployed using AWS CodePipeline, I can have the environment variables set in the CodeBuild stage where I would be building the jar and eventually a docker image in this stage. Something like this.

```
EnvironmentVariables:
  - Name: PORT
    Value: "{resolve:secretsmanager:DBCredentials:SecretString:port}"
```

The error is `Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'PORT' in value "${PORT}"`

Comment: Could you please show the list of error when you run the program?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the react approach ! But in spring for using multiple environments, it's better to have a properties file or yaml by environment.

Ps: File name must be named like `application-{environment name}.properties` and must be in the resources folder.

**For dev:** 
File name : `application-dev.properties`

```
server.port=8089
```

**For IT:** 
File name : `application-it.properties`

```
server.port=8090
```

In the `application.properties` file, where usually we put some shared properties between all the environments, we can add the propertie : `spring.profiles.active = dev` // you can put what you want depending on your needs. If you have more than one profile you can separate them by " `,` ".

For more details you can check [spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: If you are using GitHub, I am assuming you would not save the credentials there. How would you handle it?

Comment: You are talking about a security subject ! There are many approaches, you can put a crypted password ...., If the solution above resolve your issue, flag it as solved to close the question